# Question on proof regarding solvability of congruences modulo powers of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

The following theorem was left as an exercise in K. Ireland and M. Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*. The theorem is as follows:

> Let $2^l$ be the highest power of 2 dividing $n$. Suppose that $a$ is odd and that $x^n \equiv a \mod 2^{2l + 1}$ is solvable. Then $x^n \equiv a \mod 2^e$ is solvable for all $e \geq 2l + 1$.

The text says that one begins by assuming that $x^n \equiv a \mod 2^m$ (for some $m \geq 2l + 1$) is solvable and that $x_{0}$ is a solution to the congruence. Then $x_{1} = x_{0} + b2^{m - l}$ satisfies $x_{1}^n \equiv a \mod 2^{m+1}$ for an appropriately chosen $b$.

I am particularly interested in the specific case when $n = 2$, so then $l = 1$ and we assume that $x^2 \equiv a \mod 2^m$ is solvable for some $m \geq 3$ with $x_{0}$ a solution. If we let $x_{0}^2 - a = 2^m k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then (with $b$ still yet to be chosen) we have that $$x_{1}^2 - a = x_{0}^2 + 2^m b x_{0} + b^2 2^{2m - 2} - a = (x_{0}^2 - a) + 2^m b x_{0} + b^2 2^{2m - 2} = 2^m(k + bx_{0}) + b^2 \cdot 2^{2m - 2}$$

At this point I was hoping that it would be apparent how I should select $b$, but it still is not. Since $m \geq 3$, then  $2m - 2 \geq m + 1$ and so $b^2 \cdot 2^{2m - 2} \equiv 0 \mod 2^{m + 1}$. Thus it suffices to have $k + bx_{0} = 2$ (or equal to some power of 2 greater than 2 itself).

I thought that selecting $b = 2x_{0} + k$ would work, however this leads to $$k + bx_{0} = k + (2x_{0} + k)x_{0} = k + 2x_{0}k + kx_{0}$$ and I still unable to factor out a 2 from the whole expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We work with your particular example, but the general argument is almost the same. As you wrote, we want to find $b$ such that
$$x_1^2-a\equiv (x_0^2-a)+2^m bx_0\pmod{2^{m+1}},$$
or equivalently such that
$$bx_02^m \equiv -(x_0^2-a)\pmod{2^{m+1}},$$ that is,
$$bx_02^m \equiv -k2^m \pmod{2^{m+1}},$$
or equivalently 
$$bx_0\equiv -k\pmod{2}.$$
Note that we "cancelled" a  $2^m$ from all the terms, *including* the modulus. More generally, we have $cx\equiv cy\pmod{cz}$ if and only if $x\equiv y\pmod{z}$. This is an immediate consequence of the definition of congruence.

Finally, since $x_0$ is odd, $bx_0\equiv -k\pmod{2}$  has a solution $b$.

Comment: In general $ax\equiv ay\pmod{am}$ if and only if $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$.  The proof follows directly from the definition of congruence.

Comment: @Oiler: Working directly with integers is I think more intuitive, at least for students I have had in beginning number theory classes.

Comment: @Oiler:  First of all, with your choice of $x=y=3$, of course $x\equiv y\pmod{6}$. But my claim is different, it is not mod $6$. We divide everything, including the **modulus**, by $a$. Note that in the comment the first modulus was $am$, and the second was $m$.